# Spring Boot DB Migration with Flyway to MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, flyway

I have a Gradle Spring Boot web application that migrates from H2 to PostgreSQL using Flyway. I am trying to convert this to migrate from H2 to MySQL. The build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'war'


war {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    archiveName = 'demo.war'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    compile("com.h2database:h2")

    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41")

    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")    

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}
```

There is an application.yml file:

```
error:
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false

amazon:
  associate_id: habuma-20

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

---
spring:
  profiles: production
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/readinglist
    username: habuma
    password: 
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

In build.gradle, I replaced

```
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41")
```

with

```
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5")
```

and changed application.yml to

```
error:
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false

amazon:
  associate_id: habuma-20

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

---
spring:
  profiles: production
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/readinglist
    username: root
    password: ******
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

To get the "production" profile I set an environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production. Then run with the command java -jar build/libs/demo.war. When the application tries to boot up I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private readinglist.ReaderRepository readinglist.SecurityConfig.readerRepository; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readerRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1c65a791' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1c65a791': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 1
```

I'm not sure what the solution to this Checksum mismatch is.

Comment: Do you have any applied migrations in mysql database? It seems like you have already applied migration in mysql with version 1 and this migration has another checksum of sql-file.

Comment: I'm still not that familiar with the migration process. What I did was take an applied migration file (V1__initialize.sql) for postgreSQL and modify it to be compliant with MySQL then try to apply the migration to MySQL. So I created an empty database in MySQL then ran the application to apply the migration.

Comment: This message "Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 1" appears if you have applied migration with the same version but different checksum. (https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-3.2.1/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/info/MigrationInfoImpl.java). So you have applied migrations, but on which DB? So first of all, check that spring boot applied production profile and use mysql connection instead H2 (You use in dev profile, right?). The last. "migrate from H2 to MySQL", what does it mean? Flyway is about incremental updates of one DB, not migrate from one to other.

Comment: This example is from the Book Spring Boot In Action and was downloaded from GIT. It sounds like you're saying there has already been a migration applied. If so, it would have been to PostgreSQL. This was not a migration I did, it would be a migration the author did before submitting the code to GIT. Before I ran the project, I reconfigured it to use MySQL, then modified the migration file V1__initialize.sql to be compliant with MySQL. Then I ran the project and got the error. I'm sure the production profile is being applied. Can I "reset" things and start over with MySQL instead of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Was the code from this repo (https://github.com/habuma/sbia-samples)? I've tried to do the same (ch08/readinglist_war, right?) and all OK. Migrations was applied normally (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL). But I make .war and manually deploy it to my Tomcat (actually I haven't managed with eclipse plugin). In console I got:  Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
 Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/migration_test (MySQL 5.6). Did you got something like that in you server output? And which command did you use for running application?

Comment: My code was from book website download at www.manning.com/books/spring-boot-in-action. I was running via java -jar /build/libs/demo.war. I copied demo.war to Tomcat8's webapps and started Tomcat8. Got the same error in log files, app crashed. Then I downloaded the git source, modified it, copied demo.war file to Tomcat8's webapps directory again and reran. This time the code ran and the conversion worked. I got my tables in MySQL and was able to use them. I guess there is a problem with the source code from the book website. The zip files from git and the book's website are not quite the same.